# Using jQuery with Directives in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datatables

I'm using Angular UI bootstrap tabs and jQuery datatables. However, the jQuery to instantiate the datatables is getting fired before AngularJS processes the directive. Please advise.

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Heading 1">
        <div id="my_div_container">Some dynamic content</div>
        <table id="myTable">
          <tr>
             <th>Column 1</th>
             <th>Column 2</th>
             <th>Column 3</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Value 1</td>
             <td>Value 2</td>
             <td>Value 3</td>
          </tr>
    </tab>
</tabset>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("document").ready(
        function($) {
            $('#my_div_container').html('my jQuery content');
            $("#myTable").dataTable({
                 aLengthMenu : [ [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ],
                    [ 10, 25, 50, 100, "All" ] ]
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: using jquery like this with angular.. is a code smell.. write an angular directive to handle this scenario

Comment: Tabset is a directive in: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs. I don't think there is a directive for the jQuery datatables (as nice anyways) and it does a LOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
<tabset has-datagrid>
   <tab></tab>
</tabset>

module.directive('hasDatagrid', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            // angular finished the processing the tabset and tab now. 
            // ok to access the dom at this point
            element.find('#my_div_container').html('my jQuery content');
            element.find("#myTable").dataTable({
                    aLengthMenu : [ [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ],[ 10, 25, 50, 100, "All" ] ]
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It is a directive in Angular UI: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs. I have a minified version of that. Do I need to get the unminified and edit the link function? I don't want it to occur with every use of that directive. Ideally, I would want a tabset.ready() event.

Comment: It was a good idea... the link function gets fired before the tab content is added:
<div class="tab-content">
    <!-- ngRepeat: tab in tabs -->
  </div>

Comment: Got it working... just put the has-datagrid on the table / element itself within the tabs. Thanks!